# EJB security concerning exposing a @remote view

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, ejb

I need to expose a `@remote view` for an EJB so that it can be requested from other Java applications (running in different JVMs). I was wondering, what security concerns should I take care of so that the data exchanged is secure and that there is no unauthorized access.

At a minimum, I think the connection should be encrypted using SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering purely in terms of Security,

1. Include auth(hashed using sha2/md5) mechanism in the EJB receiver class to address **authorization**.
2. Enable **https** mandate for **authenticity**.
3. Use **hybrid** cryptography(private key to share the public key, and the public key to encrypt the data in and out) this will reduce the overall time taken. This addresses **confidentiality**.
4. Take care of corner case attack vulnerabilities like **DOS/DDOS**. Several others like **MOM** are taken care already by the public cryptography.

These are basic ones that I can think of. Once you implement them you can strengthen your application/system further.

Hope this helps.